# Coding HMA Long and Short Positions

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to code a long/short position entry on pine editor using the HMA indicator I coded.

```
`//@version=3
study(title="HMA", overlay=true)
n=input(title="period",type=integer,defval=14)

//HMA calculation for current day
wma1=2*wma(close,round(n/2))
wma2=wma(close,n)
diff=wma1-wma2
sqn=round(sqrt(n))

//HMA calculation for previous day
NextDaywma1=2*wma(close[1],round(n/2))
NextDaywma2=wma(close[1],n)
NextDaydiff=NextDaywma1-NextDaywma2

//different colors depending on the trend of the HMA
hma=wma(diff,sqn)
hma2=wma(NextDaydiff,sqn)
c=hma>hma2?blue:orange
plot(hma,color=c, linewidth=3)`
```

I also added a full stochastic to this, but I figured I'd just focus on this one thing for now.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I took a blank strategy template from the pine editor (you can load these by clicking open and pressing load blank strategy) and dumped in your conditions. I also upgraded you to version 5. (If you're going to learn pine it will be easier to learn once, plus its just better). Notice I used a long or short from the color rules of your MA. There are other options like crossovers as well, but this will get you going.

```
//@version=5
strategy("My Strategy", overlay=true, margin_long=100, margin_short=100)

n           = input(title='period', defval=14)

//HMA calculation for current day

wma1        = 2 * ta.wma(close, math.round(n / 2))
wma2        = ta.wma(close, n)
diff        = wma1 - wma2
sqn         = math.round(math.sqrt(n))

//HMA calculation for previous day

NextDaywma1 = 2 * ta.wma(close[1], math.round(n / 2))
NextDaywma2 = ta.wma(close[1], n)
NextDaydiff = NextDaywma1 - NextDaywma2

//different colors depending on the trend of the HMA

hma         = ta.wma(diff, sqn)
hma2        = ta.wma(NextDaydiff, sqn)
c           = hma > hma2 ? color.blue : color.orange
plot         (hma, color=c, linewidth=3)

long        = hma > hma2
short       = hma < hma2

if (long)
    strategy.entry("My Long Entry Id", strategy.long)

if (short)
    strategy.entry("My Short Entry Id", strategy.short)
```

Cheers and best of luck with your trading and coding